# How do I retrieve a variable's content using Python Requests module?

Tags: javascript, python, dom, python-requests

I started a little personal project just for fun. I hope posting what I'm doing here doesn't break any of the local rules. If so, let me know and I'll take the question down. No need to flag me for anything

I'm trying to pull the background image URL of my chromium homepage. Just for reference, the URL is https://www.mystart.com/new-tab/newtab/  When going to this page, nice background images are loaded.  I'm trying to grab those images for personal, not commercial, use.

What I've traced down is that the page listed above calls out to another similar page: https://www.mystart.com/new-tab/newtab/newtab/   Currently, on line #1622 through #1636, two significant lines read:

```
var fastload    = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('FASTLOAD_WALLPAPER_557b2c52a6fde1413ac3a48a'))
...
var url = fastload.info.cache_url || fastload.info.data_uri || fastload.info.image;
```

The value returned in the *url* is the URL to the background image.  If I drop into the Chromium console and use:  `console.log(url)`, I see the exact data I'm trying to scrape.  I'm wondering how I do that through python, since the actual textValue of *url* is not seen.

I have looked all over to try to find the *localStorage* object definition with no luck.  I'm pulling the page with `result = requests.get("https://www.mystart.com/new-tab/newtab/newtab/");` and then looking through `result.text`.  I've also tried using BeautifulSoup to parse through things, not that this is really any different, but still not getting the results I'm looking for.

Being that I'm a hobbyist coder, I feel like I'm missing something simple.  I've searched for answers, but I must be using the wrong keywords.  I'm finding a lot of answers for parsing the urls that can be read, but not from the contents of a variable.

Answer (score 1):

if you look at the requests being made, [there is JSON response](https://www.mystart.com/api/get_background_stats_extension/?ext=557b2c52a6fde1413ac3a48a&lang=en&startdate=1970-01-01) with info for 350 images. `image_id` is used in the url, e.g.
`https://gallery.mystartcdn.com/mystart/images/<image_id>.jpeg`
so for `id=154_david-wilson-moab`:

https://gallery.mystartcdn.com/mystart/images/154_david-wilson-moab.jpeg

Parse the JSON and get url for all images.

Note: this is not an answer of your question, but it looks like XY problem - this solves the underlying problem of retrieving image urls.

Comment: Thank you.  This is what I'm looking for.  I can parse the JSON data, but where exactly did you find that?  And can you help me understand how to request that specific JSON data through python?

Comment: It depends on your browser, but it's the developers tools, e.g. for Firefox https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Network_Monitor

Comment: I'm truly struggling trying to find that JSON response you linked to.  I've been looking all through the Chrome Dev Tools responses.  It's obviously there, but I'm not locating it.  Obviously I could just take what you sent me and pull all the links there, but I'd like to run a script every few months and just have it get the updated list, parse the URLs from the JSON data, and pull the images.  Where did you look specifically in the dev tools to see that JSON response?

Comment: Yes, I also found that it is not always there. I was able to get it again after closing the browser and opening new window. I also deleted cookies for the site. So, yes, it's not always there and at the moment I am not sure when it shows. Also, I open the side-bar with different images and reload the page so that it gets the stats for them

Comment: Also, there is another JSON - https://www.mystart.com/api/get_promobanner_feeds/?a=getExts&ext=557b2c52a6fde1413ac3a48a Have a look at the different themes and extension ids

Comment: Yes.  I like that you're finding the JSON responses.  I'm still searching for it.  I don't know where to look though.  I've tried searching for mystart.com/api with no results in the text of the /newtab page.  I've even searched for "how to find a json result in dev tools."  I can't believe I'm struggling with something that sounds so basic.

Comment: It is not in the page source, but in the _Network monitor_ tab - see the link above.